# Uniquely Identify a USB camera

Tags: c#, usb, webcam

I am using C#.

I am using DirectShowLib to enumerate a list of usb cameras in my network.

I get 2 cameras back. They are:

**webcam#1**

Name:
USB Camera

Path:

*@device:pnp:\?\usb#vid_045e&pid_0770&mi_00#6&26bce921&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global*

**webcam#2**

Name:
Professional financial camera

Path:

*@device:pnp:\?\usb#vid_1871&pid_0d01&mi_00#6&ba6589a&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global*

Now I cannot rely on the name of the camera to uniquely identify it as I may have more than 1 camera from the same manufacturer.

Now, am I correct in saying that the path value is a dynamic value relation to which usb port it is plugged into or is there a part of that path that is the mac/guid of the webcam.

Any guidance...
thanks

Comment: http://community.silabs.com/t5/Interface-Knowledge-Base/Windows-USB-Device-Path/ta-p/114059

Comment: Added it as an answer instead.

Comment: @RonBeyer HI, I am still reading the page. It seems you cannot have a unique id for the usbs if the usbs are the same make and model. I would jsut like to leave the question open for a bit in case some one knows different. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://community.silabs.com/t5/Interface-Knowledge-Base/Windows-USB-Device-Path/ta-p/114059 for information on USB path strings.

Please note however, that at least prior to Windows 7, this format was known to change between service packs and may be an unreliable method in older versions of windows.